# Below code doesnt work in IE 8. Is there any alternative to this?

Tags: jquery

// Get all tds with bg color \n

```
$("#table1 tr td div input").filter(function() {
    return ($(this).css('backgroundColor') === 'rgb(255, 153, 153)'); 
 });
```

Comment: Use CSS class instead of `backgroundColor` property, then statement can be simplified as `$("#table1 tr td div input.yourClass")` no need of `filter`